# Help Understanding FFT Plot?

Tags: fft

I want to analyze FFT and Harmonics of my signal.
As a proof of concept I tested FFT against standard signal.
I am unable to understand why the frequency output is going to -1. Shouldn't it be +1 at `+pi` and `-pi`.

Code :

```
x = -pi:0.01:pi;
sin_x = sin(x);
fft_x = fft(sin_x);

subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x, sin_x),
grid on;

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x, fft_x),
grid on;
```

Plot :

[image]

---

Updated Question

How can I get energy of the signal against frequencies as it can be viewed in spectrum analyzer or FFT signal on oscilloscope?

Comment: The DFT (Discrete Fourier Transform) is mathematically challenging. I recommend starting with a good texts or grad level class. Here is an example: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mdft/

Answer (score 3):

Because $\sin(x) = -\sin(x+\pi)$.

The definition of DFT is

$$
X(k) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} x(n) e^{-j2\pi kn/N}
$$

You may notice that $n$ goes from $0$ to $N-1$. Although the time index of your signal is from $-\pi$ to $\pi$, DFT has no idea of it and assumes it starts from $0$. That means the signal send into `fft` is actually `-sin([0:0.01:2*pi])` resulting in a negative frequency output.

Comment: How can I get energy of the signal against frequencies as it can be viewed in spectrum analyzer or FFT signal on oscilloscope?

Comment: To get energy against frequency, just calculate $|X(k)|^2=X(k)X^*(k)$, or you can use [pwelch](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html) to get a power spectral density (PSD) estimate.

Answer (score 2):

Your command `plot(x, fft_x)` plots only the real part of the complex-valued `fft_x` sequence. Try the following MATLAB code to see if it makes more sense to you:

```
figure(1)
subplot(3,1,1), plot(real(fft_x)), grid on
subplot(3,1,2), plot(imag(fft_x)), grid on
subplot(3,1,3), plot(abs(fft_x)),  grid on
```

Your example has a subtle anomaly. The real part of the FFT of a single cycle of a sine wave should be all zeros. That's not your case because your `sin_x` sequence is not *exactly* a single cycle of a sine wave. For your `sin_x` sequence to be exactly a single cycle of a sine wave its last sample must be equal to the negative of the second sample of `sin_x`.

Comment: How can I get energy of the signal against frequencies as it can be viewed in spectrum analyzer or FFT signal on oscilloscope?

Comment: Do your words "How can I get energy of the signal against frequencies" mean "How can I plot the spectrum of your time-domain signal?"

Comment: I have been asked to plot all frequencies present in the signal and latter also analyze the Total harmonic Distortion. So one can say plot the spectrum of your time-domain signal and/or energy of each frequency component in the signal.

Comment: Well, ...compute the DFT of your time signal, compute the magnitude of the complex-valued DFT samples, and plot the first half (positive-frequencies) of the magnitude samples over a frequency range of zero -to- Fs/2 Hz. Next, measure magnitude of the "fundamental" spectral component and the magnitude of all its visible spectral harmonics, and apply those measured magnitude values to some "total harmonic distortion" equation.